# Visa4uk application refunds

Tags: uk

I have recently cancelled my visa4uk application because I applied for the wrong visa type. I already submitted my refund request and even email the Ukvi that cost me £5.60. They escalated my case today to the relevant department, does it mean refund would be on its way or there is still chances that refund might be rejected.

I submitted my application yesterday, paid for it and then cancelled the application within an hour.

Would my refund be approved?

Anyone has similar experience please advise.

Comment: @Giorgio What you say is true, but people with similar experiences may be able to offer helpful information nonetheless.